# redefine __init__

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a class from a library and I want to modify the behaviour of the constructor.

I am doing:

```
from library import TheClass

TheClass._original_init = TheClass.__init__

def f(self, *karg, **kargw):
  print "hello"
  self._original_init(*karg, **kargw)

TheClass.__init__ = f
```

is it the correct approach? I have problem in this specific case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import axes
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

axes.Subplot._original_init = axes.Subplot.__init__ 

def f(self, *karg, **kargw):
    def add_minor_locator(axis, n = 5):
        ticklocs = axis.get_ticklocs()
        diff = ticklocs[1] - ticklocs[0]
        minorLocator = MultipleLocator(diff/float(n))
        axis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
    add_minor_locator(self.get_xaxis())
    add_minor_locator(self.get_yaxis())

    self._original_init(*karg, **kargw)

axes.Subplot.__init__ = f

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
```

I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1319, in get_xaxis
    return self.xaxis
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work. Do you have any actual problems with this approach?

Comment: I would rather inherit from the original class than monkey-patching it unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: What are advantages of this method over subclassing and overriding the `__init__` method?

Comment: Any reason why won't you simply subclass `TheClass` with overwritten `__init__` instead monkey-patching the constructor?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:yes, I've extended the question

Comment: You know about [decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)?

Comment: @dm03514: the name of the class doesn't change

Comment: @wiso: You can still stick the subclass in place of the original class. :-)

Comment: As a warning, `matplotlib` does some magic (that I don't fully understand, or remember exactly at the moment) to create the `Subplot` class on the fly.  Forgetting exactly what is going wrong with the classes here _why_ are you trying to do this?

Comment: @tcaswell: I am doing this because I want that all the plots I made have this kind of ticks. Unfortunately it is not possibile to do that changing the rcParams.

Comment: @wiso To be clear, what you really want to do is set there to be `n` minor ticks per major tick on all graphs?

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that the original `__init__` has already run; `self.get_xaxis()` should only be called *after* initialization has taken place:

```
def f(self, *karg, **kargw):
    _original_init(self, *karg, **kargw)

    def add_minor_locator(axis, n = 5):
        ticklocs = axis.get_ticklocs()
        diff = ticklocs[1] - ticklocs[0]
        minorLocator = MultipleLocator(diff/float(n))
        axis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
    add_minor_locator(self.get_xaxis())
    add_minor_locator(self.get_yaxis())
```

Comment: you are right, but now I got another error: `raise RuntimeError('Locator attempting to generate %d ticks from %s to %s: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS'%(len(locs), locs[0], locs[-1]))
RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 87501 ticks from 0.0 to 3500.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS`

Comment: @wiso: that's because you are values on the locator that are out of bounds. That is a problem with your `add_minor_locator()` code, not with the way you patched the class. Your patch is otherwise working.

Comment: @wiso: I have *zero* domain knowledge here. I can help you with patching arbitrary classes and point out why it didn't work in this case, but that error requires domain knowledge of matplot axes that I lack.

Comment: @wiso: I presumed you knew what you were doing by adding this code in. :-)

Comment: @wiso: Perhaps adjust your ticks to stay below the minimum? You seem to want to have 25 ticks *per step*.

Comment: @wiso the problem is that you are setting the step for the `MultipleLocator` based on the default ticks (`[0, 1]` in steps of `0.2`) so every time you make an axes you the set the minor tick step to be `.2/n`, thus when you change the axis range later, it blows up because you are still using the tiny minor tick spacing.